# Launch application from commandline on usb Connected non-jailbroken iOS device

Tags: ios

How to launch  specific application on non jailbroken iOS device from commandline . I have gone across libimobiledevice but didn't get the command to do the same .I am able to list and take screen shot of the connected device but was not able to launch app from the device ?

Answer (score 0):

libimobiledevice has a tool called idevicedebug. Use it like this:

```
idevicedebug run 'app bundle name'
```

In order to get list of bundle names installed on device use:

```
ideviceinstaller -l
```

In order for this to work, you app must be debuggable.